# I get 413 nginx error when uploading a file

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, cicd

I am getting 413 error when trying to upload file, below is the code of my nginx.conf and docker-compose

nginx.conf:

```
http {
    client_max_body_size 500M;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 194.58.119.116;

        root /var/www/public;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.php;

            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization';
                return 200;
            }
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass app:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }
    }
}
```

docker-compose:

`version: '3.8'

services:
nginx:
image: nginx:latest
volumes:
- ./:/var/www
- ./.docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
ports:
- "80:80"
depends_on:
- app
container_name: ${CONTAINER_PREFIX}_nginx
environment:
PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT: 512M
PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE: 500M
PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE: 500M

app:
image: $REGISTRY/dev/app:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
environment:
- APP_NAME=$APP_NAME
- APP_KEY=$APP_KEY
- APP_ENV=$APP_ENV
- APP_URL=$APP_URL
- DB_CONNECTION=$DB_CONNECTION
- DB_HOST=$DB_HOST
- DB_PORT=$DB_PORT
- DB_DATABASE=$DB_DATABASE
- DB_USERNAME=$DB_USERNAME
- DB_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD
- APP_DEBUG=$APP_DEBUG
volumes:
- ./:/var/www
depends_on:
- db
container_name: ${CONTAINER_PREFIX}_app

db:
image: postgres
restart: always
volumes:
- /var/lib/postgresql/data
environment:
POSTGRES_DB: $DB_DATABASE
POSTGRES_USER: $DB_USERNAME
POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
ports:
- "5432:5432"
container_name: ${CONTAINER_PREFIX}_db

`

I added the directive client_max_body_size 500M; But now instead of my site I get Unable to connect

Answer (score 0):

client_max_body_size 500M;

must be inside the server tag

```
server {
...

client_max_body_size 500M;

...
}
```